# MySQL 'Date' objects are actually Strings

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Have a bit of an issue that I'm stuck on;

Currently working on a Springboot project, where I am looking to take in two dates (Start Date & End Date) from the UI, process the data within the controller, and return a list of data between the given dates.

The problem I'm having is that my 'Date' objects in the database are actually Strings. Unfortunately, simply changing the values to 'Dates' isn't an option (over 10,000) entries.

I have tried the following, but having no luck:

Java Controller:

```
//Input params format: 2023-02-27 // YYYY-MM-DD
@RequestMapping("/neteng/topten")
public Iterable<BaseData> getTopTen(
        @RequestBody Map<String, String> dates) {
    
    String startDate= dates.get("startDate");
    String endDate= dates.get("endDate");

    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    
    try {
        java.util.Date date = sdf.parse(startDate);
        java.util.Date date2 = sdf.parse(endDate);
    
        java.sql.Date sqlStartDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()); 
        java.sql.Date sqlEndDate = new java.sql.Date(date2.getTime()); 
    
        baseDataRepository.findBydateBetween(sqlStartDate, sqlEndDate);

        return baseDataRepository.findBydateBetween(sqlStartDate, sqlEndDate);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    
    return "SomeErrorPage";


}
```

POJO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="base_data")
public class BaseData {

@Id //Set primary key
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")//Specify the column name
private Long baseDatatableId;
private Date date; // Have tried keeping this a String
...

public BaseData() {

}

public BaseData(Date date_time, ...) {
    this.date = date_time;
    ...
}
//Getters & setters
```

JPA Repo:

```
public interface BaseDataRepository extends JpaRepository<BaseData,Long>{

    List<BaseData> findBydateBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate);

}
```

SQL Script & Sample data snippet:

```
CREATE TABLE `base_data` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
....
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `Operator_idx` (`operator`)
)  ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1001 DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8MB4 COLLATE = UTF8MB4_0900_AI_CI;

INSERT INTO `base_data`
VALUES      (1,
         '1/11/2020 17:18',
         ....)
```

The `create table` statement originally had a `varchar` for the date, I have changed it to `Date` as I thought that might help. If I can get a solution with keeping everything as `String/Varchar`, I would prefer to go with that, but I don’t think that would work as it’s not possible to query “date-in-range” if the values are strings?

Comment: You say your dates are stored in the database as string.However your create table statement uses the date type. And your POJO class matches the date type.  Something is weird here.

Comment: Don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`.  Never ever.

Comment: If your table is created with that `create table` statement declaring `\`date\` DATE DEFAULT NULL`, then the dates are not actually strings. How they are stored internally I don’t know, and you have no need to care. And obviously when you query them, strings are printed -- this is the same for numeric data types, etc. Your MySQL considers them dates, and you should handle them as dates and trust that they are dates.

Comment: The create table statement originally had a varchar for the date, I have changed it to Date as I thought that might help. If I can get a solution with keeping everything as String/Varchar, I would prefer to go with that, but I don’t think that would work as it’s not possible to query “date-in-range” if the values are strings? Happy to be corrected

Comment: (1) It may not be easy to change the existing table with many rows to use `date` instead of `varchar`, but I still think that this should be the way to go. Keeping dates in `varchar` will give you all kinds of issues during the lifetime of your system. (2) You are correct that querying dates before, after or between other dates would be *very complicated* at best when dates are stored in `varchar` in `dd.MM.yyyy` format.

Comment: something like this? https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-custom-types

Comment: Write a SQL query that uses the `to_date` function of the database to convert the string to a date. Then use that as the value to do the comparison. You will need to use something like that or convert the table to use a proper timestamp/date whatever the type is you need. Unrelated but a performance killer, you are calling your `findByDateBetween` method twice...

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the comments. A variation of all the input from everyone, and the answer from M. Deinum solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is to modify the table in your database and use the proper data types for the columns. If it is a date, make it a date.

The next best thing is to use your database and convert the string to a date before comparison. This will mean you need to write a custom SQL query to get the results, instead of using the automatic features of Spring Data JPA.

```java
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM base_data WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i'), nativeQuery=true) BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate")
List<BaseData> findBydateBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate);
```

This should give you the result you need, however it might be slow as for each row it needs to convert the string to a date.